# Is it possible to apply Geometry nodes?

Tags: export, geometry-nodes

I have used geometry nodes to scatter objects at the vertices of a plane. I'd now like to apply this so it becomes a mesh and then I can export it into other software. Is this possible in 2.92 or any of the experimental builds?

Comment: You would think that using the 'Apply' action of the Geometry Nodes modifier would apply the changes... however, this simply seems to remove the modifier without changing the geometry. Since Geometry Nodes is still under development it would seem likely that that particular functionality has not yet been developed.

Comment: It does not work in 2.92 but I believe it works in 2.93

Comment: I downloaded the most recent daily build of 2.93 and that still didn't seem to work.

Comment: Yeah same here. I was able to recreate the same effect with particles and convert to mesh, but it's not quite as simple of a solution.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need, but "make instances real" is one way, but is going to be a mesh per object

Comment: That is exactly what I need - thanks very much Amir.

Comment: The issue with Realize Instances is that the object will lose some data during the process, like vertex color, and I don't understand why...

Answer (score 19):

If It's Blender 3.0 use the node *Realize Instances*, then apply the modifier. The  *Realize Instances* node basically converts the geometry nodes into real geo.

Comment: It's also very helpful, when you need to add other modifiers AFTER Geometry Nodes, which won't work otherwise

Comment: If my scattered objects aren't real, then what are they? I don't understand what this node does.

Comment: Thank you!  Possibly the most useful geometry nodes information I've run into yet!  (Also works in Blender 4, BTW.)

Answer (score 1):

you can just use the "realize instances" node which will make the instances "real" and they will be a part of your mesh after applying the modifier.

More info: https://youtu.be/VynJrxedBuQ
(1 min)